# reverse to "at time zone" in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to convert timestamp to 'Europe/Zurich' timezone and get the utc_offset automatically since it depends on daylight saving time or not (either GMT+1 or GMT+2)

For example: 9:00:00 (timestamp without time zone) to become 11:00:00 ('Europe/Zurich')

```
at time zone 'Europe/Zurich'
```

gives me however 07:00:00

I can do a join with table pg_timezone_names and set

```
time_stamp + utc_offset
```

but there might be a quicker/more optimized solutions out there. Something like 'of time zone'...

Many thanks!!

Comment: select '2013-10-07 09:00:00 UTC'::timestamptz at time zone 'Europe/Zurich'

gives me "2013-10-07 11:00:00". And for you?

Comment: the column is a timestamp without time zone so my query would go like   select '2013-10-07 09:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Zurich' gives 7:00:00. However your answer is correct, casting it to timestamptz first and do at time zone is a perfect code. Thanks a lot!!